# Grouping occurences of a string to a row

Tags: r, plyr

**tl;dr**
*Is there a way to group together a large number of values to a single column without truncation of those values?*

---

I am working on a data frame with 48,178 entries on RStudio. The data frame has 2 columns of which the first one contains unique numeric values, and the other contains repeated strings.

```
----------
id    name
1     forest
2     forest
3     park
4     riverbank
.
.
.
.
.
48178   water
----------
```

I would like to group together all entries on the basis of unique entries in the 2nd column. I have used the package "ddply" to achieve the result. I now have the following derived table:

```
----------
type         V1
forest       forest,forest,forest
park         park,park,park,park
riverbank    riverbank,riverbank,
water        water,water,water,water
----------
```

However, on applying `str` function on the derived data frame, I find that the column contains truncated values, and not every instance of each string.

The output to the `str` is:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ type: chr  "forest" "park" "riverbank" "water"
 $ V1  : chr  "forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,f"| __truncated__ "park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,park,pa"| __truncated__ "riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverbank,riverba"| __truncated__ "water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,water,w"| __truncated__`
```

How do I group together same strings and push them to a row, without truncation?

Comment: Try this: `sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$name), split = ','), length)`

Comment: That should work! The problem is that there are truncated values in the column from which we are trying to get the count.

Comment: I want all instances of the character to be grouped together, I suppose due to space constraint the data frame truncates the instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131020/discussion-between-fabulous-and-chirayu-chamoli).

Comment: Please edit any additional information into your Question (not comments). Also please make all your examples reproducible. Help others help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your Q and include the `ddply` code you have used. This may help to better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer of *HubertL*, the `str()` function does exactly what it is supposed to but is perhaps the wrong choice for what you intend to do.

From the (rather limited) information you have given in your Q **it seems that you already have achieved what you are looking for**, i.e., concatenating all strings of the same type.

**However, it appears that you are stuck with the output of the `str()` function.**

Please, refer to the help page `?str`.

From the *Description* section:

> Compactly display the internal structure of an R object, a diagnostic function and an alternative to `summary` (and to some extent, `dput`). Ideally, only one line for each ‘basic’ structure is displayed. It is especially well suited to compactly display the (abbreviated) contents of (possibly nested) lists. The idea is to give reasonable output for any R object.

`str()` has a parameter `nchar.max` which defaults to 128.

> `nchar.max` maximal number of characters to show for `character` strings. Longer strings are truncated, see `longch` example below.

The `longch` example in the *Examples* section illustrates the effect of this parameter:

```
nchar(longch <- paste(rep(letters,100), collapse = ""))
#[1] 2600
str(longch)
# chr "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"| __truncated__
str(longch, nchar.max = 52)
# chr "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"| __truncated__
```

### Maximum length of a character string

According to `?"Memory-limits"`, *the number of bytes in a character string is limited to 2^31 - 1 ~ 2*10^9*. Given the number of rows in your data frame and the length of `name` the concatened strings won't exceed 0.6*10^6 which is far from the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the results in a list using base R split() function:

```
new.list <- split(df, f=df$type)
```

This will split the data frame into multiple data frames that can be accessed using square brackets.  It keeps the character strings from being combined and truncated as the records continue to be preserved in separate cells.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are not really truncated, only their display by `str` are truncated:

```
size <- 48000
df <- data.frame(1:size, 
                 type=sample(c("forest", "park", "riverbank", "water" ), 
                             size, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

res <- by(df$type , df$type, paste, collapse=",")


str(res)
 'by' chr [1:4(1d)] "forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,forest,f"| __truncated__ ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ df$type: chr [1:4] "forest" "park" "riverbank" "water"
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.default(data = df$type, INDICES = df$type, FUN = paste, collapse = ",")


lengths( strsplit(res, ','))
   forest      park riverbank     water 
    11993     12017     11953     12037 

sum(lengths( strsplit(res, ',')))
[1] 48000
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a count of occurance, then why not simply use `table` ?

```
df<- read.table(head=T, text="id    name
1     forest
2     forest
3     park
4     riverbank")
df
df1<- as.data.frame(table(df$name))
#will give you number of times the word occurs

# if for some reason you want a repetition,then 
x<- mapply(rep,df1$Var1,df1$Freq)
y<- sapply(x,paste,  collapse=",")
data.frame(type=df1$Var1, V1=y)
```